# Jenkins envInject Plugin not picking PATH

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have my Jenkins configured to `Inject environment variables to the build` process and set the `Properties File Path` to `G:\Jenkins\env.properties`

Inside my `env.properties`

`VISUALSTUDIOVERSION=12.0`
`PATH=$PATH`

When I run my job, the PATH is not reflecting my system path instead its just showing `$PATH` only. How can I edit my `env.properties` file to pick up system PATH?

THe output of Env variables after build is

`VISUALSTUDIOVERSION=12.0`
`PATH=$PATH`

But I am expecting to see it as

`VISUALSTUDIOVERSION=12.0`
`PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Perl\site\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Perl\bin;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables in Java are case-sensitive. Try *Path* instead of *PATH*.